# Why is Emacsclient inserting quotes around output strings?

Tags: emacsclient

I would like to have output from Emacsclient without quotes, but

```
$ emacsclient -s my-server -e '(princ "hello")'
```

gives output:

```
"hello"
```

Expected output would be:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of the `princ` function happens in the server Emacs, in this case, `hello` is echoed in the echo area.

`emacsclient` in the other hand, prints the return value of the expression, which is the string `"hello"`.

For example:

```
emacsclient -s my-server -e '(progn (princ "hello") 1)'
1
```

Here, `hello` is still being echoed in the server Emacs, however, `emacsclient` prints `1`, as this is the value of the expression.

Comment: Thanks.. but I am not sure I understand completely.. Then why is `emacsclient -s my-server -e '"hello"'` still printing `"Hello"` and not `Hello`?

Comment: But `emacsclient -s my-server -e "'hello"` works..

Comment: Maybe I could use something like: `emacsclient -s my-server -e '(make-symbol (princ "Hello"))'` ?

Comment: `emacsclient` prints the value of the expression. A symbol would print like `hello`, but a symbol with a space would print like `hello\ world`. As far a I know, there is no way to make `emacsclient` print anything other than a read:able representation of a lisp object. However, you could write a simple wrapper script in your favorite scripting language (like Ruby) that starts `emacsclient` is such a way that it stores the output in, say, a file, which the wrapper script could pick up and print.

Comment: @HåkonHægland The printing of the string is a side effect of the function. This side effect happens inside Emacs. The evaluation in `emacsclient` doesn't return the side effect, it returns the last element of the expression, which in your OP is `"hello"`. In Lindydancer's example, the last element is `1`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland for example, try doing this: `emacsclient -e '(progn (princ "This is printed inside Emacs") (princ "Its not printed in the shell.") (princ "Its just a coincidence that the last element of this expression is the string you want to print"))'`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lindydancer said, a wrapper would work. Here's a simple example for Linux:

```
bash -c 'echo ${0:1:-1}' $(emacsclient -e '(caar (make-frame-names-alist))')
```

I use it to bring my emacs window into focus (I normally only have 1) by feeding its output to `wmctrl`:

```
wmctrl -a $(bash -c 'echo ${0:1:-1}' $(emacsclient -e '(caar (make-frame-names-alist))'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know the name of your server, I suspect the `server-eval-at` function, called from a secondary Emacs instance running in batch mode, may be a workable solution (perhaps depending on how frequently you're planning on calling this).

Examples:

```el
emacs -Q --batch -l server --eval "(princ (server-eval-at \"my-server\" '\"Hello, world\"))"

emacs -Q --batch -l server --eval "(princ (server-eval-at \"my-server\" '(emacs-version)))"

emacs -Q --batch -l server --eval "(prin1 (server-eval-at \"my-server\" 'load-path))"
```