# print unquoted output to stdout from emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, print

I want to use `emacsclient` to let my running instance of emacs evaluate a function and print the result to a terminal.

That is, I want to do something like this:

> $ emacsclient --eval "(frame-parameter (car (frame-list)) 'name)"
>   *info*

However, instead, I get output like this:

> "*info*"

If I use `message`, the output is displayed in some frame's minibuffer and I still get quoted output (`"*info*"` instead of `*info*`).

How do I get `princ`-like output to be output to my `emacsclient` terminal?

Comment: Use `message`? Your code prints the result of evaluation, which is a string. `message` formats stdout stream.

Comment: See also [Why is Emacsclient inserting quotes around output strings?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9391/260)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `emacsclient` is the wrong way to do what I want.  I thought I could not use `emacs --batch` because I wanted to get "live" info from my running `emacs` instance.

The missing piece of the puzzle was the function `server-eval-at`:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval "(progn (require 'server) (princ (format \"%s\\n\" (server-eval-at \"server\" '(frame-parameter (car (frame-list)) 'name)))))"
*info*
```

Or, a more significant example:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval "(progn (require 'server) (princ (format \"%s\\n\" (server-eval-at \"server\" '(mapconcat (lambda (f) (frame-parameter f 'name)) (frame-list) \"\\n\")))))"
*info*
CAPTURE-3-foo-service.org
SomeClass.java
SomeOtherClass.java
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible to redirect standard output from an emacs server directly with emacsclient alone.  As you found, the only output of is the value that the s-expression evaluates to.  `server-eval-at` with `emacs --batch --eval` looks like a good option.  If you still want to use emacsclient for some reason, here's one approach that will work for capturing standard output.  I'm not sure how to capture standard error in this manner.

Since `emacsclient --eval` does not capture any of the server's standard output streams, you will need to capture it as part of your s-expression:

```
emacsclient --eval "(with-output-to-string\
  (mapc\
   (lambda (frame)\
     (princ (format \"%s\\n\" (frame-parameter frame 'name))))\
   (frame-list)))"
```

Anything printed to standard output during within the body of `with-output-to-string` is captured and returned as a string value.  You can then print that string output as Emacs otherwise (by using Emacs to interpret it):

```
emacsclient --eval '(with-output-to-string \
  (mapc \
   (lambda (frame) \
     (princ (format "%s\\n" (frame-parameter frame \'name)))) \
   (frame-list)))' \
| emacs --batch --eval '(princ \
  (concat \
    (with-temp-buffer \
      (insert-file-contents "/dev/stdin") \
      (read (current-buffer))) \
    "\n"))'
```

The same command (in one line):

```
emacsclient --eval '(with-output-to-string (princ "Hello, World!"))' | emacs --batch --eval '(princ (concat (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents "/dev/stdin") (read (current-buffer))) "\n"))'
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using emacsclient because I want to get information about my running emacs process. `epipe` might be a good solution. I'm not sure `make-symbol` is right for what I want.
Imagine I want output like "You have 37 buffers:\n- 2 are elisp-mode\n- 2 are info-mode\n...".

Comment: Would using `server-eval-at` within the same server that `emacsclient` return the same or different information?

Comment: @grettke you can use both `emacsclient --eval` and `server-eval-at` to invoke an s-expression in a particular emacs server.  Note my answer about how standard output and standard error are not printed by `emacsclient --eval`.

Comment: Thank you @ebpa.

Comment: When I use the example above with Emacs 29, piping to `emacs --batch ...` to unquote, I get `Maximum buffer size exceeded`. I have to set the `END` argument of `insert-file-contents` to some reasonable value to make it work. I have written up a bit more in https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/asil1y/comment/jm3r2a6/ -- hope that helps someone, but also grateful for any more elegant solutions.